# What permissions are needed for someone to complete a Contribution page that includes a profile

Tags: wordpress, civicontribute, profile, permissions

I've created a contribution page that users must use to become members. Before they can access the form, they must be logged-in to the WordPress site. By default, they are given the role of Subscriber.

When I first tried running the form, I kept getting the following error, indicating that the user didn't have permission to view the profile:

> Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.
>
> The requested Profile (gid=14) is disabled OR it is not configured to be used for 'Profile' listings in its Settings OR there is no Profile with that ID OR you do not have permission to access this profile. Please contact the site administrator if you need assistance.

I went into User Permissions and added a few profile related permissions, and now they can access the form, but are resented the option of registerin gas a different person, which is not an option I want to present. I can't seem to find the correct combination of permissions.

What's even stranger, to me, is that an anonymous user, that isn't logged in at all, can access the contribution page, complete with profile.

Can someone clarify what permissions a user must have in order to use a contribution page that includes a profile allowing them to edit/add their personal details, but not allow them to perform the operation for someone else?

Running CiviCRM 4.7.6 on WordPress 4.4.2.